# Antlr get Sub-Tokens

Tags: java, antlr4

Forgive me if my terminology is off.

Lets say I have this bit of simplified grammar:

```
// parser
expr : COMPARATIVE;

// lexer
WS : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+; 
COMPARATOR 
        : 'vs'
    | 'versus'
        ;
ITEM 
        : 'boy'
        | 'girl'
        ;
COMPARATIVE :ITEM WS* COMPARATOR WS* ITEM;
```

So this will of course match `'boy vs girl'` or `'girl vs boy'`, etc.
But my question is that is when I create a Lexer, i.e.

```
CharStream stream = new ANTLRInputStream("boy vs girl");
SearchLexer lex = new SearchLexer(stream);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
tokens.fill();
for(Token token : tokens) {
    System.out.print(token.getType() + " [" + token.getText() + "] ");
}
```

This prints out something like this:
9 [boy vs girl], i.e. it matches my query fine, but now I want to be able to do something like, get the sub tokens of this current token.

My intuition tells me I need to use trees, but really don't know how to do this in Antlr4 for my example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `COMPARATIVE` is a lexer rule which means it will try to make a single token from all the text that matches the rule. You should instead make a parser rule `comparative`:

```
comparative : ITEM WS* COMPARATOR WS* ITEM;
```

Since `COMPARATIVE` will no longer be considered a single token, you'll instead get individual tokens for `ITEM`, `WS`, and `COMPARATOR`.

Two side notes:

1. If whitespace is not significant, you can hide it from the parser rules like this:

   ```
   WS : ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
   ```

   You can then simplify your `comparative` parser rule to simply be:

   ```
   comparative : ITEM COMPARATOR ITEM;
   ```
2. In ANTLR 4, you can simplify character sets using a new syntax:

   ```
   WS : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so lets say that I have a rule called expr, and it actually matches many things like, `expr : ( COMPARATIVE | ACTION_VERB* WS* (LOCATION | ITEM) | COPULAR_VERB* WS* ( AGE | GENDER | TIME ) | TIME )+;` Is there a good way to go about matching expr, then easily parsing the `COMPARATIVE` tokens? or do I need to recognize that the token is `COMPARATIVE` and then generate a token stream based on that token's text?

Comment: On the side notes! Major thanks! I knew you could do this in Antlr3 but could not figure the syntax out for Antlr4 :)